# Generalized Distributive Law

Tags: set-theory

This is problem 3.11, p.29, Introduction to Set Theory, Hrbacek and Jech.

$$ 
\big( \bigcap_{a \in A} F_a \big) \cup 
\big( \bigcap_{b \in B} G_b \big)
= \bigcap_{(a,b) \in A \times B} (F_a \cup G_b).
$$

It is my attempt.

$
\begin{equation}
x \in (LHS) \\
\Leftrightarrow x \in \bigcap_{a \in A} F_a ~~ or ~~ x \in \bigcap_{b \in B} G_b \\
\Leftrightarrow (x \in F_a ~~for ~~all~~a\in A)~~or~~
(x\in G_b~~ for~~all~~b\in B).
\end{equation}
$

And,

$
\begin{equation}
x\in(RHS) \\
\Leftrightarrow x \in F_a \cup G_b~~for ~~all~~(a,b) \in A \times B \\
\Leftrightarrow (x\in F_a~~or ~~ x \in G_b)
~~for ~~all~~(a,b) \in A \times B.
\end{equation}
$

I want to change the position of phrases in each last sentences, but I'm not sure doing it preserves *if and only if* condition.

Please help my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more handsome to do the second part by proving that: $$x\notin\text{ LHS }\implies x\notin\text{ RHS }$$

---

Doing it your way the following statements are equivalent:

- $\forall a\in A\;\forall b\in B\;[x\in F_a\vee x\in G_b]$
- $\forall a\in A\;[x\in F_a\vee\forall b\in B\;[x\in G_b]]$
- $\forall b\in B\;[x\in G_b]\vee\forall a\in A\;[x\in F_a]$

This on base of the rule: $$\forall x\;[ Q\vee P(x)]\iff Q\vee\forall x\;P(x)$$

Comment: I understand your explanation, thank you! When I studied this book, I met some logical confusion. Can you recommend a basic mathematical logic textbook to me for studying undergraduate-level set theory?

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry, but I am not familiar with any mathematical textbook on logic:-(.